# How to parse "日本語にはどんな「文」の型、「文型」があるのかを考えます"?

Tags: grammar, parsing

> この本では「単語」よりも「文」を重視します。ですから、初めから「文」を扱います。現実に日本語を使う場合、「文」が基本の単位になりますし、日本語教育でも、教科書の第一課から「文」の形で入っていくことが多いからです。**日本語にはどんな「文」の型、「文型」があるのかを考えます。**

I have problems parsing and understanding the sentence correctly (in the bold). I believe どんな just modifies 「文」, but I don't understand 「文型」があるのかを考えます, specifically the あるのか part.

[Source](http://niwanoda.web.fc2.com/bunpou/00hajimeni.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence may be easier for you to parse without `、「文型」`:

> {日本語にはどんな「文」の型があるのか}を考えます。
> We will consider {what *sentence* types exist in Japanese}.

The clause enclosed in `{` and `}` is an embedded question.

`「文」の型` and `「文型」`, joined with a comma, are appositive, i.e., the latter is a rephrased version of the former. 文型 is a term that refers to basic sentence patterns of a language (for example, 英語の基本文型 look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vfKLevCuCg)). So you may think this comma is working like `, i.e.,` or `, or` here.

> 日本語にはどんな「文」の型、「文型」があるのかを考えます。
> We will consider what types of sentence, or *bunkei*, there are in Japanese.